# Restart service after edit on iptables

Tags: iptables, postgresql, service

We have a postgres DB running on Centos7. There is a lot of data in it.
Now we made an edit to our iptables-script and we've rexecuted it.

Do we need to restart our postgres-service after the run of rerun of the iptables-script (firewall)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, with a caveat. If you've changed anything to `ESTABLISHED` packets, your existing connections *might* behave differently. But, it's unlikely you did. Just see if you can still connect to it.

A little background: network packets always go through the chains you see when you do `iptables -L`; service don't have register themselves to the firewall, or anything like it.

Comment: +1 from me.  Just a note also that you can test connection either with a postgresql client, or simple telnet to the server ip/FQDN and port.